# Applying style to the active item in the HTML navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I was trying to apply some style to the active item in an HTML navigation bar, which is same as the `a` tag for the same.

To experiment this, I have taken the example from http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-hover-effect

Below is my modified code, where I basically created a new class "active" and replicated the same style for `a`:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CSS.css">    
</head>

<body>

<section style="background: #e74c3c; color: #fff;">
  <h2>Underline Stroke</h2>
  <nav class="stroke">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class = "active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nice staff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

</body>
```

CSS code:

```
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a, nav ul li a.active {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before,
nav ul li a.active:after,
nav ul li a.active:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}


/* stroke */
nav.stroke ul li a,
nav.fill ul li a,
nav.stroke ul li a.active,
nav.fill ul li a.active {
  position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:after,
nav.fill ul li a:after,
nav.stroke ul li a.active:after,
nav.fill ul li a.active:after  {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:hover:after,
nav.stroke ul li a.active:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav.fill ul li a,
nav.fill ul li a.active {
  transition: all 2s;
}

nav.fill ul li a:after,
nav.fill ul li a.active:after {
  text-align: left;
  content: '.';
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover:after {
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, the styles are not getting reflected in the "active" class in the navigation menu.

How to fix the error code?

Comment: Starting with the spelling of "active"

Answer (score 2):

**Points you need to consider:**

- If you're going to apply the `same styles for the anchor tag and the anchor tag with the class active`, you don't need to mention the active classes explicitly. It `applies it on all` regardless of that.
- If you want to have some `other styles which should be applied specifically for only active class`, you need to define that like I have just for demonstration changed the color of active class component to red.

  .active{
  ...
  }
- Third, you got the `spelling of active` wrong in your html.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before{
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}


/* stroke */
nav.stroke ul li a,
nav.fill ul li a{
  position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:not(.active):after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}

.active{
color: #555;
}
.active:after{
position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  content: '.';
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<section style="background: #e74c3c; color: #fff;">
  <h2>Underline Stroke</h2>
  <nav class="stroke">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nice staff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Update:

These two CSS styles have been updated to have the hover effect on load on the active by default.

```
nav.stroke ul li a:not(.active):after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}

.active{
color: #555;
}
.active:after{
position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  content: '.';
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. However sometimes it is required to have 'Active' class assignment without a:hover effect. For example, let say you activate an Item in the Navigation menu, based on the Browser-scroll position, it is not necessarily required to get over a:hover effect. I am curious how to replicate a:hover effect designed here to such sort of activation. Any idea?

Comment: @Bogaso Updated at the end of the post. Try to view it now, the active will have the hover effect by default. We used :not(.active) so that the transition doesn't apply on the active anchor tag but the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have any different styles to apply to just your active class.  All of your styles apply to both a element and the a.active.  If you want your a.active elements to be different, apply different styles.

```
a {
  color: #fff;
}

a.active {
  color: #34dd42;
}
```

As the previous answer said having both a and a.active on the css selector is redundant and unnecessary.  Simply applying the styles to just the a element will cover both.